# (Angular) Image won't show

Tags: html, angular, image

As the title says, the image won't display. Here is my code in my component.html

```
<div>
    <img src="logo.png" alt="...">
</div>
```

When I looked at chrome's console it gave me this error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)            logo.png
```

The logo.png  file is in the same folder as the component.html.
What's wrong with this and what can I do? 
I'm currently using Angular CLI: 1.7.4; Node: 8.11.1; Typescript: 2.8.1 Hopefully someone can help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angular is a **Single Page Application**.

This means that you have only one page, and that's `index.html`.

So, when you write your relative urls, you need to write them from `index.html`, not from where you component is.

Also, Angular CLI recommends putting your resources in the `assets` folder, and for a reason : once minified and bundled, onle the files declared as assets stay in your `dist`.

If you don't want to do that, you will need to add your image as an asset into your `angular-cli.json` file.

Comment: I see. I got it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Put your all images in the assets folder and try to load like this

```
<img src="/assets/images/logo.png" alt="...">
```

As, Angular try to load all the static content like images, fonts etc from the assets folder.

Comment: a quick question is proceeding slash required in the path  would not this work `"assets/images/logo.png"`

Comment: @Vikas the first forward slash should not be there. Your "assets/images/logo.png" works.

Comment: I am not sure but I always use path proceeding with slash

Comment: Got it now. Thanks for the help!